# What is the meaning of Underfined offset: -1 ErrorException thrown from phpseclib when trying to connect to remote server?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, phpseclib

I am trying to login to a remote server using phpseclib Net_SSH2->login() function. I am getting a connection timeout error, therefore I added $ssh->getLastError() to get a more clear error message but all I get is

> exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined offset: -1'

along with the stack trace. I am wondering what does Undefined offset mean here and most importantly what does the number -1 refer to?
Thanks!!

Here's my code:

```
$ssh = new \Net_SSH2('host.address');
$key = new \Crypt_RSA();
$key->setPassword('');
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('keyfile.ppk'));
try
{
    if ($login = $ssh->login('username', $key))
    {
        \Log::error('Success');
        \Log::info($login);
        \Log::error('-----------------------');

    } else {
        \Log::error('Failed');
        \Log::error($ssh->getErrors());
        \Log::error($ssh->getLastError());
        \Log::error('-----------------------');
     }

 } catch(\Exception $e) {
     \Log::error('Exception');
     \Log::error($ssh->getErrors());
     \Log::error($ssh->getLastError());
     \Log::error('-----------------------');
 }
```

Comment: Post your code, it's impossible to answer such a vague question.

Comment: It means you're referring to an array key that doesn't exist, indexs start at 0, not -1. The code probably looks like `for($i = 0; $i >= count($x) -1; $i++) $arr[$i]....` but never checks if `$x` is not empty. Therefore, you get `$arr[-1]`

Comment: @Jaquarh - not in your example.  `$i` starts at 0 and is incremented by 1 during each successful loop. Nowhere is `$i` decremented...

Comment: Usually when you get an exception you get a line number. What's the line number you're getting? Maybe post the contents of keyfile.ppk? Maybe the contents would enable people to reproduce the problem? If it's an actual production key maybe you could create a new key that could be shared that reproduces the problem? Also, do you know what version of phpseclib you're using? You're using the 1.0 branch it looks like are you using 1.0.1 or 1.0.13 or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured that the exception is being thrown from inside the login function of php seclib.
The reason was that I had to white-list my IP address on the target server, so it was the attempt to connect to the target server that was failing due to a timeout.